# Implementing a thread level request execution context in Java

Tags: java, tomcat

We are using a Java web application on top of Tomcat 8.
The control flow for any API in the web app is:

Servlet -> Service Layer -> DAO/DB Layer

Now we want some information about the request execution to be populated in the Service/DAO Layer which would be used in the Servlet layer(this is by design and hence can't be changed).

One way to do this is to create a ThreadLocal in servlet and pass it to all layers but this requires changing method signature and hence is quite intrusive change for our application.

The other way would be to implement something like threadLocal by keeping a static map where key is threadID and value is a list. Any layer can write/append to the map for that threadID and at the end of the request, its read by the top layer.

Are there any other ways of doing this?

**Edit 1- More information on the setup**

The top layer has a throttling interceptor which needs to know 2 things per request which is populated by downstream layer:
 - operations consumed(e.g DynamoDB IOPS etc) which is known to DAO layer.
 - Whether the request was throttled .
This information is updated in the the `token bucket` throttling engine.

Comment: One common way to pass parameters around is `setAttribute()` on the `request` object.  Does this not work for you?  (90% of the time, `ThreadLocal` is pernicious.  I'd stay away unless you're sure you can handle it properly.)

Comment: `implement something like threadLocal by keeping a static map where key is threadID`  This is basically what ThreadLocal does.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If map having key threadID then i think threadLocal instace in map also not required. One request is processed by one thread then you will get same theredID throughout in Sevices and DAO.

Comment: To understand better, can you please give an example of such an information that you want "to be populated in the Service/DAO Layer which would be used in the Servlet layer"?

Comment: @SreeKumar Added info in the edit